# numpy to speed up char and substring counts?

Tags: python, numpy, substring

anyone here tried to use numpy to count string characters and substrings?
For example:

```
for string in string_list:
    c = np.array(list(string))
    counter = Counter(c)
```

It is ok to count 1 char, but for substrings there are any function to speed up things for large data?

For ex I have this:

```
k = 1
test_1mer = Counter()

for name, seq in parse_multi_fasta_file_compressed_or_not('test/test_random.faa'):
    test_1mer.update(get_kmers(seq, k))
```

Fasta file (test_random.faa):

```
>header
SGFAVAGBHNAAMMAAM
```

I am using this code to count substrings in a file of 65GB.
It takes many hours to finish. So I think about numpy to speed up things a lil bit. With some biult in function to try to improve a little bit.
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw)

Comment: If you need to speed up more generic code (i.e. also non-vectorizable code), you can try numba.

Comment: When does the performance become problematic? Is there any way some improvements to the design of the program could be made?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using a numpy.ndarray here? That is almost surely going to slow down your solution.

Comment: I t was just a ex to look for some biult in function to speed up the count or something. That's not real code. I was thinking in using some like this numpy.char.count() instead of Counter, but it doesn't quit do what I need. So if you have some suggestion it would be appreciate.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have fast compiled code to handle strings.  It depends, in one way or other, on the Python string methods.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing numpy arrays is not the fastest operation and it doesn't appear you need any numpy specific tools; I'd recommend just passing the strings themselves to `Counter`:

```py
In [192]: strings = ['awerawe', 'awerawer', '23432wefeaf', 'awefpi32']
     ...: sum(map(Counter, strings), start=Counter())
Out[192]: 
Counter({'a': 6,
         'w': 6,
         'e': 7,
         'r': 3,
         '2': 3,
         '3': 3,
         '4': 1,
         'f': 3,
         'p': 1,
         'i': 1})
```

If instead, you'd want to count words you can just pass `strings` to `Counter`:

```
In [193]: strings = ['awerawe', 'awerawer', '23432wefeaf', 'awefpi32']
     ...: Counter(strings)
Out[193]: Counter({'awerawe': 1, 'awerawer': 1, '23432wefeaf': 1, 'awefpi32': 1})
```

Comment: Hi there sat-die I used this kind of stuff in my original code. I edit my first post. 8)